# In Java type arguments, does <? extends E> mean strictly subtypes only? or would E also suffice?

Tags: java, generics, super, extends, bounded-types

In Java type arguments, does  mean strictly subtypes only?  or would E also suffice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `super` and `extends` gives inclusive lower and upper bounds respectively.

Here's a quote from [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#FAQ103):

> #### What is a bounded wildcard?
>
> A wildcard with an upper bound looks like `? extends Type` and stands for the family of all types that are subtypes of `Type` , type `Type` being **included**. `Type` is called the *upper bound*.
>
> A wildcard with a *lower bound* looks like `? super Type` and stands for the family of all types that are supertypes of `Type` , type `Type` being **included**. `Type` is called the *lower bound*.

Comment: This doesn't reflect my observations. If I write method that accepts `<T extends E>`, I get error if I try to pass E instance.

Comment: @TomášZato: The answer is correct; example: http://ideone.com/hRZFlu. Suggest removing the comment (and flagging this one as obsolete). If there's a specific example you have where it doesn't seem to work, you might want to post a question about that, it's probably something similar but different. :-)

Answer (score 7):

It's not strict; `E` would suffice.

Comment: I presume the converse is true as well?  i.e. <? super E> is not strict and can mean E as well.   Thanks!

Comment: Yes, E satisfies <? super E> as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<? extends Animal> animalList=new List<Dog>();
List<? extends Animal> animalList=new List<Animal>();
```

Both the lines compile without any error.
Any function taking the list as a parameter understands that the objects in the list are of type E or a subtype of E.