# Understanding Java bound generic type within collection

Tags: java, generics

I have a collection of with generic bound type, defined like that:

```
Set<? extends BasicShape> shapes = new HashSet<>();
```

In my implementation (and for the sake of this question), BasicShape **IS NOT** abstract.

I would have expect then to be able to do:

```
shapes.add(new BasicShape())
```

but I can't, failing with compile error:
[image]

[I have verified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136680/in-java-type-arguments-does-extends-e-mean-strictly-subtypes-only-or-would), and extends is inclusive - that means that it includes the upper bound itself (in my case - BasicShape).

I Could not find an answer to this particular question in other SO threads.

Can someone explain me that behavior ?

Comment: `Set<T extends BasicShape> shapes = new HashSet<>();` cannot compile. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Why not Set<BasicShape> ? (Also, what Tunaki said.)

Comment: Did you mean `Set<? extends BasicShape>`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: this is a theoretical question for a course I am about to deliver. Technically for my specific usage I could omit the bounding, but these kind of cases can occur in reality one way or another and I want to fully understand them.

Comment: You should use <? super BasicShape> in order to add a BasicShape, and <? extends BasicShape> in order to iterate on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `shapes` as

```
Set<? extends BasicShape> shapes = new HashSet<>();
```

this means you can assign to that variable a `Set<BasicShape>`, a `Set<Rectangle>`, a `Set<Circle>`, etc...

Therefore you can't add any `BasicShape` to `shapes`, since (as far as the compiler can tell) you may be trying to add a `Circle` to a `Set<Rectangle>`.

If you change the declaration to :

```
Set<BasicShape> shapes = new HashSet<>();
```

you can add any `BasicShape` instance to that `Set`.

Comment: the compiler can't tell if I am adding a Circle to a Set<Rectangle> as well. Why would it fail me only when trying to add new BasicShape and not by adding new Circle ? if it will be only the assignment issue - wouldn't I just get an unchecked assignment in case I will actually do an assignment ? because for now I am not assigning anything, just trying to populate the collection with items... In addition, what's the point of stating that extends is inclusive, if I can't actually include it's type ?

Comment: @aviadcohen The compile time type of `shape` in your example is `BasicShape`, but its runtime type can be a `Circle`. Since generics are only applicable at compile time (before they generic type parameters are erased by the compiler), the compiler doesn't allow adding `shape` to `shapes`. If you try to add a `Circle` to a `Set<Rectangle>` the compiler will also give you an error.

Comment: @aviadcohen When you have a `Collection<? extends BaseType>` variable, you can't add anything to it, since you don't know which sub-type of BaseType this Collection can contain. You can only get elements from the Collection and be certain that they are all instances of BaseType. This is part of the PECS term (Producer Extends Consumer Super) - in this example - a `Collection<? extends BaseType>` can produce instances of BaseType but it can't consume them.

Comment: I think I finally got it (using your answers + observing similar threads @Tunaki referenced to).